# QT Layout different for different buttons

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a grid layout that creates a grid no problem.

I have created buttons from A-J which coincide with the grid.

The current display is:

[image]

I want to layout the A-J buttons to correspond with the grid.

[image]

How can I achieve this Layout in PyQt5?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QStyle, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QPainter, QFont, QIcon, QPixmap, QPalette, QLinearGradient, QColor, QBrush, QCursor
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt

grid = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

BTN ='font-weight: bold; color: {};font-size: 14px; background-color: {}; padding: 20px;border-width: 2px; border-radius: 50px;'

class _QPushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(_QPushButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))   

class App(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 1200
        self.height = 800
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        # Background
        p = QPalette()
        gradient = QLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.0, QColor('#f1f1f1'))
        gradient.setColorAt(1.0, QColor('#00a1de'))
        p.setBrush(QPalette.Window, QBrush(gradient))
        self.setPalette(p)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.btnA = _QPushButton('A')
        self.btnB = _QPushButton('B')
        self.btnC = _QPushButton('C')
        self.btnD = _QPushButton('D')
        self.btnE = _QPushButton('E')
        self.btnF = _QPushButton('F')
        self.btnG = _QPushButton('G')
        self.btnH = _QPushButton('H')
        self.btnI = _QPushButton('I')
        self.btnJ = _QPushButton('J') 

        self.createGridLayout()

        windowLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        for i in range(len(grid[0])):
            print(i)
            lbl = QLabel()
            lbl.setText(str(i+1))
            windowLayout.addWidget(lbl)

        windowLayout.addWidget(self.btnA)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.btnB)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.btnC)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.btnD)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.btnE)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.btnF)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.btnG)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.btnH)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.btnI)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.btnJ)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
        self.setLayout(windowLayout)
        self.center_widget()

        self.show()

    def createGridLayout(self):
        font = QFont("Sans Serif", )
        font.setPixelSize(18)

        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox()
        self.horizontalGroupBox.setFont(font)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        for i in range(0, len(grid)):
            for j in range(0, len(grid[1])):                
                try:     
                    btn = _QPushButton(str(grid[i][j][0]))
                    if grid[i][j][1] == 'GREEN':
                        btn.setStyleSheet(BTN.format('white', 'green'))
                        layout.addWidget(btn, i, j)
                    elif grid[i][j][1] == 'RED':
                        btn.setStyleSheet(BTN.format('white', 'red'))
                        layout.addWidget(btn, i, j)
                except Exception as e:
                    btn = _QPushButton(str(grid[i][j]))
                    btn.setStyleSheet(BTN.format('black', 'white'))
                    layout.addWidget(btn, i, j)
                    # print(grid[i][j][0], e)                


        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def center_widget(self):
        self.window().setGeometry(
                QStyle.alignedRect(
                    Qt.LeftToRight, 
                    Qt.AlignCenter,
                    self.window().size(), 
                    QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry())        
        )   



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I see that you have modified the image, in your initial image you indicated that at the top there were numbers from 1 to 7, but now it is not. Is not the numbers necessary?

Comment: Yes I tried to put it at the top of `createGridLayout` and it did nothing.. When I put it at the bottom it loaded them in.  It is fine at the bottom also.. The main problem is the A-J buttons being horizontal and not vertical.

Comment: the first image does not correspond to the code that you show, I think you should show your last code to avoid confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had updated it!.. I have now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick was to use `QFrame` as a base and in them place the buttons:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import string

grid = [[["text", "GREEN"], 0, ["text", "RED"], 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

BTN = """QPushButton{{font-weight: bold; color: {};
        font-size: 14px; background-color: {}; 
        border-width: 2px; border-radius: 100px}}"""


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()
        self.createLayout()
        self.center_widget()

    def initUI(self):
        p = self.palette()
        gradient = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.0, QtGui.QColor('#f1f1f1'))
        gradient.setColorAt(1.0, QtGui.QColor('#00a1de'))
        p.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QBrush(gradient))
        self.setPalette(p)

    def createLayout(self):
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        frameL = QtWidgets.QFrame()

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(frameL)
        frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        frame.setObjectName("principal")
        frame.setStyleSheet("#principal{border: 2px solid white;}")
        hlay.addWidget(frameL)
        hlay.addWidget(frame)

        gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(frame)

        h = 60  # height

        for i, row in enumerate(grid):
            frameButton = QtWidgets.QFrame()
            frameButton.setFixedHeight(h)
            frameButton.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(frameButton)
            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("{}".format(string.ascii_uppercase[i]))
            button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
            lay.addWidget(button)
            vlay.addWidget(frameButton)
            for j, val in enumerate(row):
                gridButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
                gridButton.setFixedSize(h, h)
                if isinstance(val, list):
                    gridButton.setText(val[0])
                    if val[1] == "GREEN":
                        gridButton.setStyleSheet(BTN.format('white', 'green'))
                    elif val[1] == "RED":
                        gridButton.setStyleSheet(BTN.format('white', 'red'))
                else:
                    gridButton.setStyleSheet(BTN.format('black', 'white'))
                    gridButton.setText("{}".format(val))
                gridLayout.addWidget(gridButton, i, j)

        for ix in range(j + 1):
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel("{}".format(ix + 1))
            label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            gridLayout.addWidget(label, i + 1, ix)
        vlay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel())

    def center_widget(self):
        self.window().setGeometry(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.alignedRect(
                QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight,
                QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter,
                self.window().size(),
                QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry())
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: That's great but there is only one issue.. I want to add this line in but it only remembers `j`.. `button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.populate_row("{}".format(string.ascii_uppercase[i])))`

Comment: I do not understand you, what is the problem?

Comment: I want each button to send the string of the label of the button to this method to fill each one row at a time.. use the enumerate loop, it only passes `J` for every button `A-J`..I want each button to be like. `button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.populate_row('A'))`, `button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.populate_row('B')...`

Comment: I realise I did not have that in the question... I have updated to show you how it was..

Comment: @johnashu I think you know with your reputation that you can not drastically change your question, in your initial code or in the explanation of your question points out that, if now you have another question create another post. The current question is: **I want to generate this design but I can not.**

Comment: Fair point! apologies! I added it after but did not double check!:) I will take it out and generate a new question instead!

Comment: @johnashu I also recommend trying to solve this problem, I am disappointed that you publish a post without taking the time to try to solve it. Nowhere in your question is there populate_row.

Comment: I always take the time to try and solve it.. I added populate_row after I posted the question and did not double check.. I am sorry to disappoint! certainly not my intention!